# How to change FloatingActionButton's properties

Tags: codenameone, floating-action-button

I tried to change the size, position and the transparency of the Floating button (both in GUI Builder and programmatically) without any success. How can I do that? (I changed the attributes of FloatingActionButton-UIID.)

thanks in advance
babür

Answer (score 0):

The position of the FAB is determined via margin and it's bind method. The bind method accepts two int values that match the component constants e.g.:

```
FloatingActionButton.bindFabToContainer(cnt, Component.LEFT, Component.TOP);
```

Will place the FAB in the top left instead of the default bottom right.

When setting the margin make sure to set it for unselected/selected and pressed otherwise it won't work.

The size of the FAB is `3.8mm` by default, you can customize it using:

```
FloatingActionButton.setIconDefaultSize(mySizeInMM);
```